# error while using immutant server to access page from browser

Tags: clojure, pedestal, immutant

```
$ lein new pedestal-service peddy
```

and then add following file to immutant folder

```
(ns immutant.init
  (:require [immutant.web :as web]
            [io.pedestal.http :as http]
            [peddy.service :as app]))

(web/start-servlet "/" (::http/servlet (http/create-servlet app/service)))
```

after that

```
$ lein immutant deploy peddy
```

and then

```
$ lein immutant run
```

immutant server stated with nrepl

but when i try to open page in browser it throws error

I am using immutant 1.1.4 and pedestal-service 0.4.0

stack-trace of error

```
ERROR [io.pedestal.http.impl.servlet-interceptor] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) {:line 293, :msg "error-stylobate triggered", :context {:io.pedestal.impl.interceptor/terminators (#<servlet_interceptor$terminator_inject$fn__11550 io.pedestal.http.impl.servlet_interceptor$terminator_inject$fn__11550@7681d2d5>), :io.pedestal.impl.interceptor/stack (#io.pedestal.interceptor.Interceptor{:name :io.pedestal.http.impl.servlet-interceptor/terminator-injector, :enter #<helpers$before$fn__9159 io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers$before$fn__9159@76b5905>, :leave nil, :error nil}), :io.pedestal.impl.interceptor/execution-id 1, :servlet #<FnServlet io.pedestal.http.servlet.FnServlet@4b4b3283>, :servlet-config #<Dynamic org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperFacade$Dynamic@1e733d96>, :servlet-response #<ResponseFacade org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade@28a7423c>, :servlet-request #<RequestFacade org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2f3f5533>}}: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Interceptor Exception: No matching field found: getContentLengthLong for class org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade {:execution-id 1, :stage :enter, :interceptor :io.pedestal.http.impl.servlet-interceptor/stylobate, :exception-type :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, :exception #<IllegalArgumentException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: getContentLengthLong for class org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade>}
    at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke(core.clj:4403) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:]
    at io.pedestal.impl.interceptor$throwable__GT_ex_info.invoke(interceptor.clj:37)
    at io.pedestal.impl.interceptor$try_f.invoke(interceptor.clj:53)
    at io.pedestal.impl.interceptor$enter_all_with_binding.invoke(interceptor.clj:140)
    at io.pedestal.impl.interceptor$enter_all$fn__8979.invoke(interceptor.clj:156)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:]
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:]
    at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1862) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:]
    at io.pedestal.impl.interceptor$enter_all.invoke(interceptor.clj:154)
    at io.pedestal.impl.interceptor$execute.invoke(interceptor.clj:272)
    at io.pedestal.http.impl.servlet_interceptor$interceptor_service_fn$fn__11571.invoke(servlet_interceptor.clj:399)
    at io.pedestal.http.servlet.FnServlet.service(servlet.clj:28)
    at immutant.web.servlet.ServletProxy.service(servlet.clj:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.x.slim.incremental.18.jar:7.2.x.slim.incremental.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45-internal]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: getContentLengthLong for class org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField(Reflector.java:271) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:315) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:]
    at io.pedestal.http.impl.servlet_interceptor$add_content_length.invoke(servlet_interceptor.clj:206)
    at io.pedestal.http.impl.servlet_interceptor$request_map.invoke(servlet_interceptor.clj:224)
    at io.pedestal.http.impl.servlet_interceptor$enter_stylobate.invoke(servlet_interceptor.clj:255)
    at io.pedestal.impl.interceptor$try_f.invoke(interceptor.clj:50)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using Immutant 2? It's very possible the latest version of Pedestal is incompatible with Immutant 1.

Comment: all our old production system is in immutant 1.x so 
I am planning to upgrade to immutant 2.x

Comment: is there any good production set up and deployment docs for immutant 2.x..?

Comment: If you're embedding it, you would follow deployment guidelines for any Clojure application. If you're running it on WildFly, you should follow the guidelines for WildFly.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by Pedestal [using .getContentLengthLong()](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/0.4.0/service/src/io/pedestal/http/impl/servlet_interceptor.clj#L206), which was [added](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getContentLengthLong%28%29) in version 3.1 of the Servlet spec. Immutant 1.x is based on JBoss AS 7, which uses version 3.0 of the spec. This means you won't be able to use Pedestal 0.4.0 in any pre-3.1 container.